# MediaStream events active and inactive are not triggered in a remote WebRTC Peer Connection

Tags: html, html5-video, webrtc, mediastream

I have a **remote** `MediaStream` object obtained by a remote `WebRTC Peer Connection`.

**I want to check when the remote** `MediaStream` **becomes inactive** (indipendently by the reason).

I have read that for this purpose I should use the events `active` and `inactive` of the `MediaStream` object.

**But these two events are never triggered**: even if I set a specific handler for these two events, the handlers are never executed.

Here my implementation:

```
function onRemoteStream(event) {
    event.stream.addEventListener("active", function(){
    console.log('The video is active');
    }, false);
    event.stream.addEventListener("inactive", function(){
        console.log('The video is not active');
    }, false);
    remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
}
```

The two messages are never showed.

I also tried:

```
function onRemoteStream(event) {
    event.stream.onactive = function(){
        console.log('The video is active');
    };
    event.stream.oninactive = function(){
        console.log('The video is not active');
    }
    remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
}
```

But the behaviour is the same.

I don't understand why the two events are not triggered.

I'm using Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m

Answer (score 1):

No it is working properly, it is just that you cannot directly write a function for that event (As per the documentation which is now removed). You can also log your `event.stream` object in console and see the details. You have to use predefined properties `onactive` and `oninactive`

I have made a quick code to test how to trigger these events.

**HTML**

```
<video src="" autoplay id="video"></video>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var video = document.getElementById('video')

function onactive() {
  console.log("on active event");
}

function oninactive() {
  console.log("on inactive event");
}

navigator.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:false}, function (stream) {
  stream.onactive = onactive;
  stream.oninactive = oninactive;

  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}, function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})
```